Polyline renders in different thickness in Firefox and Chrome despite having the same stroke-width
I have an SVG Polyline that renders in two difrerent thickness in different browsers - Thicker for Chrome and thinner for Firefox. Would anyone know why? And how would I fix it such that the two have the same thickness? I prefer a solution that does not rely on detecting which browser is running.
The polyline itself is declared simply with the points being generated by code:
<polyline
    transform="translate(0 0)"
    points="" // Computer-generated points
    stroke="#142e52"
    stroke-width="1"
    fill="none"
    vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
></polyline>

Playground link
Firefox 127.0.1:

Chrome 126.0.6478.63:


The Polyline renders exactly the same for me in both Chrome and Firefox (current versions, on Ubuntu)

@TusharJadav do you use a High DPI screen? That might play a part because the screenshots above are taken on a High DPI screen

Nested svg works differently in Firefox than Chrome. I don't think Chrome is following the SVG spec here.

Is there somethign I can do to make them render with the same thickness? @RobertLongson

Unnesting the SVG is not an option because they're used to group and position the elements

I guess you'll need to raise a Chromium bug then and either wait for a fix or fix it yourself.

I assume you're using a kind of a "graph generation" script. If so, you should consider to optimize the graph generation output to get a more robust SVG rendering output. For instance scale the quite low amplitude vertically to avoid massive browser based transformations (based on nested SVG viewBoxes and dimension attributes). In other words: your current design is quite demanding for browser SVG rendering sub systems – if you can pre-calculate some scaling or reduce the amount of scaling (e.g using <g> elements with transfom attributes/properties you can avoid a lot of problems.

Firefox will support vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke screen" from version 129 that should give you something closer to what Chrome does but you may still have to detect which browser is running because Chrome doesn't support the screen keyword yet.
